Tooltip Angular appear even if my mouse is not on a button when i close a modal
I have a button with a tooltip that appears when I hover over it. When I click on the button, a modal opens, and the tooltip disappears. However, when I close the modal, the tooltip reappears even though the mouse isn't over the button.
I try to put tooltip.close() when I click on the button, but it doesn't work

please share minimal reproducible code!
